# Matrix Semilogx linestyle and linewidth change

Tags: matlab, plot, styles, colormap, linestyle

I need some help making some changes in the way my plot is plotted with this code.

First of all, I need dark colours. I want my the lines to start from black and slowly go to dark red/purple. Scaling from black to dark red/purple smoothly.

The other thing I need is on how to get other variations in my linestyle. I stole the linestyle code from somewhere and it is kinda useful, but I need more than the 4 variations given.

I also wanna add another line, with semilogx again and add it on the legend. How can I achieve that without messing with the previous legend? If I just add the line and put an extra line on the legend, it gives me the wrong color. (if I just use hold on and add an ,'', in the legend it gets a parula color and not the actual color)

```
fig = semilogx(SMPSFIN(1,5:75),z);
numLines = length(fig);
cmap = colormap(parula(numLines));
style = {'-','--',':','-.'};
for i = 1:numLines
    fig(i).Color = cmap(i,:);
    set(fig(i),'Linewidth',i*sqrt(1.5*i)*0.1);
    set(fig(i),'linestyle',style{1+int8(mod(i,4))});
end
```

Thanks a lot for your time :)

Comment: There are only 4 available [line styles](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/chartline-properties.html#property_LineStyle), maybe you can use [markers](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/chartline-properties.html#property_Marker) instead.

Comment: adding to the previous comment, while these are not linestyles per-se , they will work: `.-.` , `-^` , `-o` , `-*`. `:*` ...etc...